# Linebreak on multiples columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

```
.multiplecolonnes {
    width:250px;
    -moz-column-width:300px;
    -webkit-column-width:300px;
    column-width:300px;
    height:45em;
}
.multiplecolonnes {
    padding:-1000;
    counter-reset:lis;
}  
.multiplecolonnes {
    counter-increment:lis;
    content:' ' counter(lis);
}
```

```
<div class="panel-body panel-body-non-repetitive">
    <div id="previewHtml" class="multiplecolonnes" style="font-size: <?php echo ($taille_police);?>;">
    <?php echo (html_entity_decode($str));?>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kn05cy1p/
I have this code that allows me to display my text on several columns

The height of which is predefined. However, when there are more than 3 three columns, I would like to go back to the line. Because currently here is the result

[Multiple Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03gHB.png)

I've tried a lot of things but I can't make a line break. How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: provide your html code also.

Comment: sadly since you didn't provide a minimal and reproducable example i'll most likely not answer this question since i'm undoubtedly not going to look at it a second time. and guess what.. i'm the only one who is saying this out loud. people don't want to create a test for you. provide it yourself. we don't get payed for this.

Comment: Okay, sorry I added a JSFiddle.

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/rfzu4d1c/

Comment: Thanks, but not really. I'd like each set of 3 columns to be on a new row.

Comment: So you want the columns to be repeated.

Comment: On my link for example there are 4 columns. I would like the fourth one to be on a new line. And so on for each set of columns.

Comment: You can simply give a break like this https://jsfiddle.net/rfzu4d1c/1/

Comment: In this example yes of course. In the original code I get the text in PHP. I can't put a line break in the middle.

Comment: Divide the content in div like this https://jsfiddle.net/1p0qbLow/

Comment: Same, I can't put a div in the middle.